# Reading accuracy in Keras from the saved model

Tags: keras

Yesterday I trained the model in Keras all night, but when I tried to see the results, my computer was not working. When I turned it ON, then I saw 'model.h5' file built already, but I couldn't see the results of accuracy of my training and testing. I saved the model with 'model.save', but how can I now see the accuracy of the model only from that saved model?

Comment: What type of problem are you dealing with here ? Classification or Regression ? You can not read the accuracy of the model you will have to find it out. Do you have a test set or validation set ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the official [Keras website](https://keras.io/getting-started/faq/#how-can-i-save-a-keras-model), you have to use:

```
keras.models.load_model(filepath)
```

Example:

```
model = load_model('my_model.h5')
```

This will load your saved H5 model to 'model' and then you can try:

```
model.evaluate(x,y)
```

To return the loss value & metrics values for the model in test mode.

Comment: what is x and y here in model.evaluate(x,y)